# Encoding for marshmallow Schema for japanese characters

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

This is my simple flask-restful api. To get a name which is in Japanese.
When I run this I get

```
{"name":"\u5317\u6d77\u9053"}
```

but expected

```
{"name":"北海道"}
```

Below is the code.

```
class Prefecture(Base):
      id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      name=Column(String)

class PrefectureSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
     class Meta:
         ordered:True
         model =Prefecture

class PrefectureApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        schema=PrefectureSchema(many=True)
        values = Prefecture.query.all()
        return {schema.dump(values)
```

How to I change the unicode to characters before dumping it.I would like to continue using marshamallow as I would like to use the field.nested for my relationships.
I tried to add configuration below but it didn't work.

```
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII']=False
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```py
app.config.update(RESTFUL_JSON=dict(ensure_ascii=False))
```

Saved me lots of headache.